# Reproducing table layout with CSS display:table properties

Tags: html, css, html-table, sidebar

I have a nice layout which uses an HTML table to create a scrollable sidebar with a simple header. It works good, you can check it out here: [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fvZBA/)

Here is the outline of my solution:

```
<aside>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <header>
                    header
                </header>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="secondcell">
                <div class="remaining">
                    ...
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</aside>
<article>
  ...
</article>
```

with the following CSS styles:

```
aside { 
    position: absolute; 
    left:0; top: 0; bottom: 0; 
    width: 200px; 
}

aside header { 
    height: 100px; 
}

aside table {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.secondcell {
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
}

.remaining { 
    height: 100%; 
    background-color: red; 
    overflow-y: auto; 
}

article { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 200px; 
    padding:10px; 
}
```

But unfortunately, I'm using HTML tables which a lot of people don't like, because it's not semantic, etc etc.

So I wanted to reproduce this layout with CSS formatting, but it doesn't work.
You can check my attempts here: [jsFiddle demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/rxEAk/)

Maybe it isn't possible at all so I can't do it with CSS using only divs?

Comment: "because it's not semantic, etc etc." What?? Who said this??

Comment: Read about `<div>` and `<span>` here : http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/intermediate/spandiv/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div

Comment: anything a `<table>` can do a `<div>` + `CSS` can do better

Comment: @Novocaine88 How would you translate `colspan` to divs and css?

Comment: Any html tag must be used according to its purpose. If it's tabular data - then use `table`, if its some content in the sidebar (we see only blah-blah) so it's kinda difficult to say what tags are more appropriate. But what I know for sure - is that you shouldn't apply tabular styles to `div`s believing it's more semantic. `css` has **nothing** to do with semantics, your **html** does!

Comment: @skip405 I know that css has nothing to do with semantics. I just wanted to emphasise that a lot of developers don't like to use tables for layouting. I want to do the same layout with CSS - because I would like to use CSS for styling and HTML for "semantics".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this very simply through css

if you have the following three classes:

```
.table {display:table;}
.row {display:table-row;}
.cell {display:table-cell;}
```

you just replace all `table` tags with `<div class="table"></div>`
all `tr` tags with `<div class="row"></div>`
all `td` tags with `<div class="cell"></div>`

[Your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/fvZBA/1/)

Comment: Thanks! It works in Chrome but not in IE. But I think it's the solution for my problem, I'm just thinking about creating another question on why it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: @Zsolt, if you are not bothered about using display:table (I didn't see your second fiddle!) you can change your code and css to the following which will give you the same effect as the first fiddle without the tables: http://jsfiddle.net/fvZBA/6/.  It has ;less markup and css and is more browser compatible

Comment: Thanks! This solution is also fine!

Answer (score 0):

First you do not need display;table to produce such a layout.
You need :

1. min-height
2. float {or inline-block if one tells it's bad practice too :) )
3. overflow.

http://jsfiddle.net/aKzFZ/2

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
aside {
    float:left;
    min-height:100%;
    background:red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right:1em;
    display:table;
}
aside .remaining {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
}
aside header {
    display:table-row;
    height: 100px;
    background:white;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
.scroll {
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
article {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-right:1em;
}
```

I think not so semantic to put `<aside>` in front in the flow, stick in it a `<header>` and see nowhere a `<h1> <hX>` ... :)

Comment: Thanks but it's not a solution for my problem. I want the sidebar to be scrollable independently of the main article. I've updated my sample: http://jsfiddle.net/fvZBA/2/
Another issue that it works in Chrome, but not in IE :(

Comment: i mistook about scroling areas . see update jsfiddle.net/aKzFZ/2  same issue with FF for your jsfiddle